# How to connect customUI events to macros in Word 2010?

Tags: vba, ms-word, ribbon, office-2010

I have a MS Word 2010 macro-enabled document template (.dotm file). I am working on embedding some custom Ribbon UI components by means of a `customUI\customUI14.xml` file within the .dotm archive.

The controls show up fine, but I am unable to link up the `onAction` events described in the XML with any of the macros defined in the template. I think the method signatures are correct, but I must be referencing them incorrectly in the XML. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the XML:

```
<mso:customUI xmlns:x2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui/macro" xmlns:x1="DPOfcX.DocumentRibbon" xmlns:mso="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <mso:ribbon>
        <mso:tabs>
            <mso:tab idQ="mso:TabHome">
                <mso:group id="TestGroup" label="TestGroup" autoScale="true">
                    <mso:button onAction="SendAsEmail.SendAsEmailRibbon" idQ="x2:TestSendAsEmail" label="Send As Email" imageMso="ListMacros" visible="true"/>
                    <mso:button onAction="SendAsEmail.ShowFormRibbon" idQ="x2:TestShowForm" label="Enter Letter Data" imageMso="ListMacros" visible="true"/>
                </mso:group>
            </mso:tab>
        </mso:tabs>
    </mso:ribbon>
</mso:customUI>
```

Here are the method signatures in the `SendAsEmail` module:

```
Sub ShowFormRibbon(IControl As IRibbonControl)

End Sub

Sub SendAsEmailRibbon(IControl As IRibbonControl)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the `idQ` attributes in the `button` tags. I had originally taken these from a UI export. Once I changed them to `id`, the button events worked!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reference the module. Simply remove `SendAsEmail.` from both of your `onAction`.

Comment: I had given that a shot. The callback functions aren't getting called with or without the leading 'SendAsEmail.'